# Swagger for SpringMVC - Alternatives to Springfox?

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

Can any of you suggest any alternatives for implementing Swagger for Spring MVC based REST API?  FYI, this is not Spring boot.  I've tried Springfox, but IMHO it is a buggy mess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try using the [Swagger Maven Plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin), which is a build time annotation processor. If you're using spring-boot with JaxRS you could use [Swagger-Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core), which is pretty similar to SpringFox. It knows how to interpret JAX-RS annotations rather than the spring annotations. With all of these libraries that *infer based on implementation or annotations*, you are going to encounter bugs/problems when you have esoteric service definitions, or scenarios the library authors haven't thought about.

If your goal is just to document the RESTful endpoints, there is the excellent [Spring Rest Docs](https://projects.spring.io/spring-restdocs/), which allows you to write documentation driven by tests. It even allows you to add hand-written documentation that can augment your generated documentation. However, it keep in mind that it does not generate the service specification in a machine readable form.

That said, being the library author for [SpringFox](http://springfox.io), it would be useful if you could [create specific issues](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues) to problems you're encountering with [SpringFox](http://springfox.io). This will help improve the library for you and anyone else encountering the same bugs/issues. You can certainly rant on stack overflow, but Im afraid that may only get your question down votes at best.

Comment: It seems springfox is no more maintained (540 issues opened in GitHub and no release for more than 1 year). Isn't it ?

Comment: Springfox does not work with Spring Boot 2.1.x nor with Spring Boot 2.2.x, because of incompatible dependencies.

Comment: We've had no problem with Spring Boot 2.1.2
The issue with 2.2.x is here: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2932

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/RabiAPI/Evalon4J

This is a command line tool for generating java restful api documentation,

NO ANNOYING CONFIGURATION AT ALL!!!

Supported frameworks

- Spring MVC
- JAX-RS
- Swagger 2.0 Annotations
- OpenAPI 3.0 Annotations
- JSR303 Bean Validation